# Why merge sort two linked list changes original lists?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to merge sort two sorted linked list head1 (1->3) and head2 (2->4) by passing them into a function: merge(l1, l2). This function returns the result of merge sort (i.e. a sorted linked list). The problem is, the values of head1 and head2 changes during the merge sort, but they should keep unchanged.

How to let head1 and head2 keep their original values during the merge sort? I will be very thankful if anyone can help me address this problem.

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None


class Solution:
    def merge(self, l1, l2):
        dummyHead = ListNode(0)
        cur = dummyHead

        while l1 and l2:
            if l1.val < l2.val:
                cur.next = l1
                l1 = l1.next
            else:
                cur.next = l2
                l2 = l2.next
            cur=cur.next

            print("head 1")
            self.printList(head1)
            print("L1")
            self.printList(l1)
            print("head 2")
            self.printList(head2)
            print("L2")
            self.printList(l2)

        if l1:
            cur.next = l1
        else:
            cur.next = l2

        return dummyHead.next

    def printList(self, head):
        while head:
            print(head.val)
            head = head.next

node1 = ListNode(1)
node2 = ListNode(3)
node3 = ListNode(2)
node4 = ListNode(4)

node1.next = node2
node3.next = node4

head1, head2 = node1, node3

s = Solution()
result = s.merge(head1, head2)
```

Comment: Why do you want the `head` values to remain the same?

Comment: Because I also need to use `head` values outside `merge()`. Actually `merge()` is a part of an iterative solution of merging sort a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Once `cur` gets the value of a "real" node with `cur = cur.next`, any further assignment to `cur.next` will *mutate* that node. Since that node was either `l1` or `l2`, you actually modify the list that they belong to.

To avoid this, you must create new nodes for *all* nodes that you add to the result list.

So change this:

```
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            cur.next = l1
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            cur.next = l2
            l2 = l2.next
        cur=cur.next
```

to this:

```
        if l1.val < l2.val:
            cur.next = ListNode(l1.val)
            l1 = l1.next
        else:
            cur.next = ListNode(l2.val)
            l2 = l2.next
        cur=cur.next
```